# My transitions out are not working

Tags: html, css

My transition outs are not working, I am using the latest Chrome Browser and when I hover over the button, the transition in is working, however the transition out just cuts right off.

My CSS

```
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    .btn:active{
        transform: translate(0px, 5px);
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .blue{
        background-color: #55acee;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #3C93D5;    
    }
    .blue:hover{
        background-color: #6FC6FF;
        transition-duration: .02s;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

HTML is on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsg4e/59/).

Comment: Please fix link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the transition on the base state not the `:hover` then it will transition between **all** states.

```
.blue {
    background-color: #55acee;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #3C93D5;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #55acee;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #3C93D5;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}
.blue:hover {
  background-color: #6FC6FF;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"> <a href="#" class="btn blue">Blu</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a transition to the :hover state, not to the actual element.
It's usually better to define a transition on the element itself, and then change properties to it's states, this way it understands that whatever the state change, it should transition from one to the other.

```
.btn{
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}
.btn:active{
    ...
}
.btn:hover{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your just need to insert this on your btn main class

```
.btn{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s  ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```